# create a langchain response in a specific language

Tags: python, response, chatbot, langchain, chain

I'm making a chatbot to answer questions. The input is a PDF in Indonesian and I want answers in Indonesian too. However, when I created a prompt to answer in Indonesian, the answer given was incomplete. How do I ensure the response is complete, and how do I maintain consistency in the answers? Sometimes even though it has been explained in the prompt to answer only in Indonesian, the response still answers in English.

```
!pip install langchain
!pip install "unstructured[all-docs]"
!sudo apt-get install libmagic-dev poppler-utils tesseract-ocr libxml2 libxslt-dev
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
!pip install InstructorEmbedding
!pip install sentence-transformers
!pip install faiss-cpu
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredFileLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
import os
from langchain.llms import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.prompts.chat import ChatPromptTemplate

loader = UnstructuredFileLoader("/content/ASIP4204-M1.pdf")
docs = loader.load()
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=20)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents=docs)
embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
db = FAISS.from_documents(documents=texts, embedding=embeddings)
retriever = db.as_retriever()
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = ""
repo_id = "mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1"
llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id=repo_id, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.1}
)

template = """You are an assistant for question-answering tasks.
Use the following pieces of retrieved context to answer the question.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know.
Just answers in Indonesian language.
Question: {question}
Context: {context}
Answer:
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=llm,
    retriever= db.as_retriever(),
    memory=memory,
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt},
)
qa.run("Apa itu data?")
```

I've tried several settings such as changing chunk size, embedding model, vector store, and changing llm. but the answer generated remains the same, not full.
When I asked "What is data"
The resulting answer is like this

[This is an example of the resulting response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ4fx.png)

Comment: It seems that language models still perform better in english, have you tried generating an answer in english to explain your indonesian pdf? It's normal that the answers aren't always the same or always totally accurate. It also depends on how the pdf is written and if it's easily understandable for a language model.

Comment: the results are still truncated in English, I don't know what's causing it. This is the resulting response.

"Data, as defined by Pendit (1992) and Ralston and Reilly (Chamidi, 2004), is the result of direct observation of an event. It is a symbol that represents an object or concept in the real world and is accompanied by a specific value. It can be stored in a more concrete form, such as in written, graphic, electronic, and other forms. An example of data is the list of students in the first sem"